# Can I change the implementation class injected by spring in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, aop, interceptor

I have a class has injected by spring on the applicationContext.xml and I need change that implementation without change the applicationContext.xml.

I heard about AOP "IntroductionInterceptor" but I don't found many useful results.

Anyone can help me?

PS. Sorry my bad english, hope that give to understand.

Comment: What do you mean by change that implementation? You will have to provide a more specific example.

Comment: You can change the implementation any time or several times.

Comment: When Spring will instantiate I need intercept and try change to another implementation of the interface.

Ex. Impl1 ans Impl2 implements IInterface.
The xml archive injects Impl1 but I need to inject Impl2 and I can't edit the xml archive.

Comment: Why couldnt you edit the xml?

Comment: Because I have no access to the web application, just to JAR library that I'm developing. And the people who has access to the web application should only update the pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, here are few:

1. Write an xml file, override configuration by adding same bean id and the implementation class that you want to use, import this new xml into your existing application context.
2. Through code, base on your need you can set a new implementation before calling the code.

There could be more but mostly we have used '1' in number of projects.

If you have multiple beans with same id, spring will pickup latest one, e.g.

```
<beans>
   <import resource="a.xml"/>
   <import resource="b.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Now if both `a.xml` and `b.xml` have a bean defined with same Id, spring will use the bean defined in `b.xml`.

Cheers !!

Comment: If I write an new xml file, how can I sure that my new bean will be instantiated and don't the old bean? I have not mentioned, but I have no access to the web application, only a jar library. I think in my case this should be done programmatically, intercepting when the Sprring instantiating, like a listener. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy - If you define multiple beans with same id, spring will pickup the last one, as I mentioned we have used this approach several times when we have a common framework and custom projects build on top of it. But you can use AOP and write interceptors if that solves your purpose.

Comment: @Andy - Just edited my answer to explain spring behaviour incase of beans with same Ids.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle is, is to apply the [service locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).
Instead of injecting the bean directly, you inject a ServiceLocator which can return different implementation.

```
//ServiceLocator bean
public Class ServiceLocator {

    @Resource(name="service1")
    private Service service1;

    @Resource(name="service1")
    private Service Service2;

    public Service getService(String service) {
       return ... //service
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I say to fonZ, I can't edit the web application, and then the application should be continue with the Spring injection anyway. I need intercept when Spring will inject and change it. Something like a listener.